# bash force double quotes in command

Tags: java, bash, shell, classpath

My bash script:

```
set -x
classpath=a:b
java -cp \"$classpath\" className
```

Basically I want the command `java -cp "a:b" className` to be executed on shell.

The output is :

```
"a.sh" 3L, 55C written
rajatk@localhost:~$ bash a.sh
+ classpath=a:b
+ java -cp '"a:b"' className
Error: Could not find or load main class className
rajatk@localhost:~$
```

Why is it adding `'` before and after the `"`. How do I force remove it?

Comment: I think that's only a textual representation of what's happening, the `'` are there to show you that `"` is part of the string. You probably don't need to use the `\"` at all, did you try with only `java -cp "$classpath" className`? Also make sure you're in the correct directory before this executes.

Comment: Using literal quotes doesn't make sense. [What are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the quotes in the original command.

```
set -x
classpath=a:b
java -cp "$classpath" className
```

The quotes are only there as part of `bash`'s syntax (to treat the value of `$classpath` as a single word), not as part of the actual string passed as the argument to the `-cp` option.